# Installing Fedora onto Hard Drive: Error checking storage configuration

Tags: fedora, mount, partition, windows, dual-boot

I am trying to be able to dual boot my windows laptop.

In the setup process, navigating to `Installation Destination -> Done` with `Automatically configure partitioning` checked, the error message "Failed to save storage configuration" shows for a few seconds, and then is replaced by "Error checking storage configuration".

If instead, I try to go `Installation Destination -> Done` with 'I will configure partitioning' checked, every option I try for Mount Point doesn't take. I've tried `/`, `/home`, and `biosboot`. Each one displays the message `Failed to add new device` and `Unable to allocate the requested partition scheme`. This is with LVM set as the partitioning scheme.

When press to create the mount points automatically, the following error appears:

```
You have not defined a root partition (/), which is required for installation 
of Fedora to continue. You have not created a bootable partition.
```

Currently, I have about 88 Gib of free space shown, so I don't think the problem is a lack of memory. I'm a little out of my depth here (if that's not obvious already) Help please!

**EDIT: TL;DR** Why can't Fedora automatically configure partitioning? Short of that, what steps do I need to take to create the '/', '/boot', and 'swap' mount points myself?